# Не сохраняются данные PHP в localStorage

Tags: php, mysql, localstorage

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','blabla','blabla','blabla');
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT data, content FROM sinc");
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
echo $result['data'].": ".$result['content']."<br>"; //Данные выводятся
echo "<script>localStorage.setItem("$result["data"]", "$result["data"]")</script>"; //Данные не сохраняются в localStorage. 
//Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$result' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';'
}
```

Comment: Вы рано закрыли двойную кавычку.

Comment: да еще и элемент массива нужно писать в одинарных кавычках, раз уж переменная помещена в двойные, либо экранировать двойные внутри

Comment: `echo "<script>localStorage.setItem(".$result['data'].", ".$result['data'].")</script>";` как-то так можно ........ либо так: `echo "<script>localStorage.setItem({$result['data']}, {$result['data']})</script>";`

Comment: Ну или конкатенацию (оператор точка `.`) применяйте, если не хотите переменные внутри кавычек писать

Comment: еще лучше шаблоны использовать, и не мешать мух с котлетами.